# MVC .NET 4.6 asking if the user wants to run JS file

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I've just started a new MVC project in VS 2015 in .NET 4.6

For some reason JavaScript that worked in the last version (VS 2013) is now returning a pop-up 'Do you want to run or save ConfirmFormClick0000.js xx bytes from...' instead of running.

Any ideas why?

Here is the related code that is being run from the controller

```
 Private Function ModalValidation(Message As String) As JavaScriptResult
        Try
            Dim SB As New StringBuilder
            SB.Append("$body = $('body'); ")
            SB.Append("$body.removeClass('loading'); ")
            SB.Append("$(document).ready(function(){")
            SB.Append("$('#PopupModal').modal();")
            SB.Append("var vBody = document.getElementById('ModalBodyText');")
            SB.Append("vBody.innerHTML = '" & Message & "';")
            SB.Append("var vTitle = document.getElementById('ModalTitle');")
            SB.Append("vTitle.innerHTML = 'Validation';")
            SB.Append("vTitle.style.color = 'orange';")
            SB.Append("});")
            Return JavaScript(SB.ToString)
        Catch ex As Exception
            'Dim vError As New SendError
            'vError.MailError(60, PageName, ex)
        End Try
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the answer is to add

jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js

It now runs as it should